# Angular - iterate through objects does not compile

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to adapt an example in Angular+RxJS with dynamic search.

html:

```
<header>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchString" (ngModelChange)="inputChanged($event)" placeholder="Search">
    <button (click)="searchString = ''">Clear</button>
</header>

<div *ngFor="let result of results$ | async">
    <div *ngIf="result.data.thumbnail != 'default' && result.data.thumbnail != 'self'">
        <a [href]="result.data.url">
            <img [src]="result.data.thumbnail" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',  
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}  
  searchString = '';
  results$ = Array<object>();
  searchSubject$ = new Subject<KeyboardEvent>();
  
  ngOnInit() {  
    this.searchSubject$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), debounceTime(200), switchMap((searchString: any) => this.queryAPI(searchString))).subscribe(x => {this.results$=x.results;});
  }
  
  queryAPI(searchString: any) {   
      return this.http.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/search.json?q=${searchString}`).pipe(map((result:any) => result['data']['children']));
  }
  
  inputChanged($event:KeyboardEvent) {
      console.log('input changed', $event);
      this.searchSubject$.next($event);
  }
}
```

But it gives an error in html:

> Error: src/app/app.component.html:6:28 - error TS2769: No overload
> matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(obj: Observable<any[] |
> Iterable | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] | Iterable |
> undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable | undefined>): any[] | ...
> 2 more ... | undefined', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'object[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] |
> Iterable | undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable |
> undefined>'.
> Type 'object[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable | undefined>': source, operator,
> lift, subscribe, and 2 more.   Overload 2 of 3, '(obj: null |
> undefined): null', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'object[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
> Type 'object[]' is not assignable to type 'null'.   Overload 3 of 3, '(obj: Observable<any[] | Iterable | undefined> |
> Subscribable<any[] | Iterable | undefined> | Promise<any[] |
> Iterable | undefined> | null | undefined): any[] | ... 2 more ...
> | undefined', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'object[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable | undefined> | Subscribable<any[] |
> Iterable | undefined> | Promise<any[] | Iterable |
> undefined> | null | undefined'.
> Type 'object[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[] | Iterable | undefined>'.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error properly, it says

> Argument of type 'object[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<...> or Subscribable<...> or Promise<...>'.

It is talking about the argument to `async` pipe which is `results$` a simple array object not some observable or promise.
You can simply remove the async pipe from the template, just keep `*ngFor="let result of results$"`